# Recursively check value empty or not

Tags: php, arrays

I have to check if items with keys 2, 3, 4, 5 in the sub array with index 0 are empty or not. If empty, I need to throw an exception.

If not empty, then move to next iteration, checking items with keys 3, 4, 5, 6 in the sub array with index 1, and so on.

Items with keys 0 and 1 will always be empty so nothings need to be done with them.

So, check for items with key > 1 then 4-4 pair check if anyone is empty and then throw an exception.
here is my code

```
$array =  array(
  array('0' => '','1' => '','2' => 'Wasatch standard','3' => 'Wasatch standard','4' => '3,5,2','5' => 'English','6' => '','7' => '','8' => ''),
  array('0' => '','1' => '','2' => '','3' => 'ThisIsAtest','4' => 'Wasatch standard1','5' => '3,4,5','6' => 'English','7' => '','8' => ''),
  array('0' => '','1' => '','2' => '','3' => '','4' => 'Wasatch standard1.1','5' => 'Wasatch standard1.1','6' => '2','7' => 'Mathematics','8' =>''),
  );


for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
  checkRecursivelyIfEmpty($array[$i],array('2'+$i,'3'+$i,'4'+$i,'5'+$i));
}


function checkRecursivelyIfEmpty($value,$sumValue){
  foreach ($sumValue as $k => $v) {
    if(empty($value[$v])){
      throw new Exception("Error Processing Request");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok. So what have you tried?

Comment: You can use `foreach` and `in_array`.

Comment: @b0s3 yes tried that but not able to post that time due to network issue

Comment: @aldrin27 i had tried the mentioned one in my question

Answer (score 1):

The following function first checks whether the input is an array indeed, then checks for the indexes to be empty. If not, then it throws an exception. Furthermore, it traverses the array to see if there are inner arrays. If so, then it recursively checks them as well. After the function there is a quick demonstration of usage.

```
function checkThings($inputArray, $subArray) {
    //If it is not an array, it does not have the given indexes
    if (!is_array($inputArray)) {
        return;
    }
    //throws exception if one of the elements in question is not empty
    foreach ($subArray as $key) {
        if ((isset($inputArray[$key])) && (!empty($inputArray[$key]))) {
            throw new Exception("My Exception text");
        }
    }
    //checks for inner occurrences
    foreach ($inputArray as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($inputArray[$key])) {
            checkThings($inputArray[$key], $subArray);
        }
    }
}

//Calls checkThings for all elements
for ($index = 0; $index < count($myArray); $index++) {
    checkThings($myArray[$index], array($index + 2, $index + 3, $index + 4, $index + 5));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach` and check using  `empty($value)`

```
 foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $value = trim($value);
            if (empty($value))
                echo "$key empty <br/>";
            else
                echo "$key not empty <br/>";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array is named `$a` you can use this code. The outer loops iterates over all the arrays. The inner loop iterates from `$i+2` to `$i+5` (in the case of `$i=0`, you get 2, 3, 4 and 5) on the sub arrays. The function [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) checks that the item is set and not equal to `false` (for instance, an empty string).

```
for($i=0; $i<count($a); $++)
    for($j=$i+2; $j<$i+6; $j++)
        if(empty($a[$i][$j]))
            //Raise an error!
```